# Porting Android TabHost to Windows Phone

Tags: android, windows-phone-8.1, uwp

I'm porting one of my Android apps over to WinPhone 8.1 and 10 (UWP). The app itself uses a TabHost which loads the individual activities into each tab which are then displayed in each tab when pressed.

On WinPhone, I'm using a Pivot to do the same thing. It looks though like I need to set up the UI for the pivot items on the view with the pivot on. I can't see this as being the case as it doesn't make sense.

Is there a way to have it that pivot item 1 loads the page it links to but still has the pivot at the top?

Comment: Why do you need `Page` instances? You can define the views in seperate `UserControl`s and you can use them in the Pivot.

Comment: Thanks - I knew there had to be a simple answer. Now to make it do as it's told and display the UserControls!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to have it that pivot item 1 loads the page it links to but still has the pivot at the top?

I think you probably want to navigate the content of `Pivot` to some page when click the header of `Pivot`, if so, there is no need to use `UserControl`. What you need is a [Frame](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.frame.aspx) control.

Firstly, we need to know there is Header part and Content part in a [Pivot](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/tabs-pivot). What you need is to keep the Headers always be shown.

For example you can code like this:

```
<Pivot>
    <PivotItem Header="Page 1">
        <Frame x:Name="frame1" />
    </PivotItem>
    <PivotItem Header="Page 2">
        <Frame x:Name="frame2" />
    </PivotItem>
    <PivotItem Header="Page 3">
        <Frame x:Name="frame3" />
    </PivotItem>
</Pivot>
```

In the code behind you can navigate in this `Frame` controls for example like this:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    frame1.Navigate(typeof(MainPage));
    frame2.Navigate(typeof(Page2));
    frame3.Navigate(typeof(Page3));
}
```